# MATLAB save multiple outputs from a function many times over

Tags: matlab

In MATLAB, I am trying to create a matrix of the outputs of the built-in function `[r, p] = corr(X1,Y1);` after using this function on multiple X's and Y's. Then, I would like to consolidate all of the r and p into their respective matrices, R and P. For example, I can do this easily if I only call one output from `corr`:

```
R = [corr(X1,Y1), corr(X2,Y2); (...)
     corr(X3,Y3), corr(X4,Y4)];
```

as `corr` returns the `r` value by default. Is there a way to achieve this for `p` as well? Below is the long way that I do it, I'm just wondering whether there is a shorter and easier method like above.

First find each `r` and `p`:

```
[r1, p1] = corr(X1,Y1);
[r2, p2] = corr(X2,Y2);
[r3, p3] = corr(X3,Y3);
....
```

Then combine them into the matrix:

```
R = [r1 r2; (...)
     r3 r4; (...)
     ...];
P = [p1 p2; (...)
     p3 p4; (...)
     ...];
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You can try something along the lines of

```
for i=1:n,
  [R(:,end+1), P(:,end+1)] = corr(X(:,i), Y(:,i));
end
```

Just make sure that `R(:,1)` and `P(:,1)` are sized correctly.
Assigning `R(:,end+1)` and `P(:,end+1)` will grow `R` and `P` automatically, without your having to combine them from temporary variables by hand.

Comment: This only works if `R` and `P` are initialized to empty. Instead just index using `(:,i)`.

Comment: For best performance, initialize R and P to a matrix of the size they will eventually have to be. For example using `zeros(n,m)`. And then use indexing like @shoelzer said. Changing size of a matrix on each iteration is slower.